# How long do jobs stay in Slurm job acounting log?

Tags: slurm

The Slurm job accounting log can be accessed using `sacct`, but after a while jobs are deleted from that. How do I find out after which time period or how often this log is cleared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, beware that `sacct` will only display the jobs of the current day by default. Use `--start` and `--end` to choose a timeframe. For regular user, furthermore, `sacct` only displays the user's jobs. In that case, use `--all` to see them all.

That being said, `sacct` will depend on the backend chosen for accounting, as defined by `AccountingStorageType` in `slurm.conf`.

If `AccountingStorageType` is `accounting_storage/none` then sacct will only be able to list the jobs that are kept in the Slurm controller memory, as long as defined in `MinJobAge` (default 300 seconds) in `slurm.conf`.

If `AccountingStorageType` is set to `accounting_storage/filetxt`, meaning that accounting is saved to file, the retention time depends on the configuration of `logrotate` on that file.

If `AccountingStorageType` is set to`accounting_storage/slurmdbd`, look for the value of `PurgeJobAfter` in `slurmdbd.conf` (default is infinite).

See more information [here](https://slurm.schedmd.com/accounting.html).